# Chrome plugin reading text file on hard drive and replacing textbox content

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing a lot of work where I use sublime to code and then need to copy the contents to a web based "editor" that really sucks. I would like the contents of this textbox/editor to be automatically populated with the contents of a text file that I chose.

I don't control the web page that I'm copying code to so can't inject an applet or similar.

What I'm hoping to do is to create a plugin (I'm using chrome) with which I can select an element as target, select a text file on the hard drive (or maybe the contents of a url pointing to localhost if that's easier) and have the plugin scan for changes and update.

Any idea as to how to go about this? Maybe there's already something similar done? I googled but can't seem to find the right terms if there already is something.

Comment: Is your heart set on an old-school file? There are lots of better storage options for this kind of data.

Comment: storage is not the issue here, editing in a nice editor that I am comfortable is. I want to be able to use sublime without having to manually cut n paste between editor and browser.

Comment: I see. The text-file format is the whole point.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the contents of a local file in an extension is probably through `XMLHttpRequest`. For example, the following background script gets the content of `/etc/passwd` and prints it to the [background console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029):

```
function pollContent() {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'file:///etc/passwd');
    x.onload = function() {
        // Do something with data, e.g. print to console
        console.clear();
        console.log(x.responseText);

        setTimeout(pollContent, 5000);
    };
    x.send();
}
pollContent();
```

In order to use the previous function, you have to [declare](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) the `file://*/*` permission (or at least `file:///etc/passwd`) **and** enable the "Allow access to file URLs" option for your extension at `chrome://extensions/`.

Only the background page can get `file://` access. You need to use the [message passing API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to put the content in a textbox with a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: Thank you. This will set me on my way.